# Map not showing current location when it is on Navigation Drawer

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

My current location button is not showing in the app when it is in the navigation drawer.
[my current location button is not showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M2gAa.png)
[Side Navigation Drawer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/meEdD.png)

Unlike when I run the app when it is not in the navigation drawer.
[my current location button is showing in here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y7N4a.png)

Is there a way to show my location button even if my map is on side nav?

I already have my map `setMyLocationEnabled(true);` but my location button still won't show.

This is where I open my map (Navigation Drawer)

open.java

```
case R.id.nav_map:
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container_op,
                    new MapFragment()).commit();
```

MapFragment.java

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_maps, container, false);
```

fragment_maps.xml

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/B_hospital"
    tools:context=".MapsActivity2"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    />
```

and this my MapsActivity2.java onMapReady

```js
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        //Initialize Google Play Services
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                    == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                buildGoogleApiClient();
                mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
            }
        } else {
            buildGoogleApiClient();
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        }

        mMap.setOnMarkerDragListener(this);
        mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(this);

    }


    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }
```

Comment: If you see closely, when my location button is visible, then the blue dot of current location is also visible, and seeing your code, you are making both of them visible in onMapReady() method. So it seems like your onMapReady() method is not getting called. Debug that and see what's topping it

Comment: part or full code is not the case here. Check the scenario which I am saying.